# Apigee X Task trigger call from external application

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, apigee

I have created a simple integration in Apigee X. And I want to trigger "API Trigger" from an external application say Oracle db.
I did a few R&D where they talked about proxies, But I have not created any and have not any idea about this.
Suppose integration has a simple task to send an email. So my integration is as follows:

API Trigger --> Send email

So I want to trigger "API trigger"(says trigger ID : send_email_test) from Oracle db whenever some event occurs in Oracle it will trigger.

1. How can I perform this task?
2. What configuration or details are needed from Apigee to share with the Oracle team so that they can trigger?
3. How Oracle team can trigger? With the help of packages or something?

If I missed any point or anything I should take care of, Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call the API trigger using the APIs provided by google.

For reference see this: https://cloud.google.com/application-integration/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.integrations/execute